# transitiondrawble from left to right

Tags: android

I am using the code below to set transitiondrawable to change color but I would like to change color from left to right .How can I do that?

```
final Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        //Let's change background's color from blue to red.
        ColorDrawable[] color = {new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE), new ColorDrawable(Color.RED)};
        TransitionDrawable trans = new TransitionDrawable(color);
        //This will work also on old devices. The latest API says you have to use setBackground instead.
        b.setBackgroundDrawable(trans);
        trans.startTransition(1500);
```

Comment: To do this, you need to play with animations

Comment: How can I do that any example?